# File b'.csv' does not exist

Tags: python, pandas, csv

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("stei-c-1.csv")
```

when the code is running :

> FileNotFoundError: File b'stei-c-1.csv' does not exist

here the directory of file D:\ITB\Tugas\PTI\H4

the python file and the csv file in same location.
how to fix it, thanks !

Comment: did you try explicitly stating the path to the file `df = pd.read_csv(r"D:\ITB\Tugas\PTI\H4\stei-c-1.csv")`

Comment: give the complete file path.

Comment: ohh yeah, it's working.. thank you !

Comment: @tavifbicandra if adding the path worked then your python file is probably not in the same directory as the file

Comment: i have putting the file in same directory as the file, but isn't working

Comment: File "D:\ITB\Tugas\PTI\H4\tes.py", line 2, in <module>
    df = pd.read_csv("stei-c-1.csv")

Comment: @tavifbicandra How do you execute your script?

Comment: run in notepadd++

Comment: @tavifbicandra use `import os`
`import pandas as pd`
`directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))`
`df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(directory, "stei-c-1.csv"))`

Comment: D:\Program Files\Notepad++

Comment: when you execute from an editor the path is relative to the binary that executes it, that is to say the binary of notepad: `D:\Program Files\Notepad++ `, not necessarily of the .py and therefore it causes you the problem, with the previous method you will not have that problem anymore.

Comment: ohh yes, i got it... thank you guys !

Comment: @asynts that's not quite right, it will actually be relative from where you launch the .py

Answer (score 1):

It should simply work by giving complete path.

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"D:\ITB\Tugas\PTI\H4\stei-c-1.csv")
```

However, as other mentioned if you are standing on the same Directory path where your Files are then you don't really need to mention the Full Path otherwise best to place absolute Path.

Comment: you forgot the `r` in front of the path

Comment: @Chris,   thanks, edited that .

Comment: @Chris, Is that really needed put `r` in front?  i'm Linux guy but i saw people using that without `r` as well.

Comment: yes it is unless you specify the path with \\ like such `"D:\\ITB\\Tugas\\PTI\\H4\\stei-c-1.csv"`

Comment: Ahh! thats Glad to know, thnx a mile again.

Comment: D:\Program Files\Notepad++

Comment: Still not working for me. I'm using mac, does this work for mac too?